# What is the best algorithm to determine whether or not a one word substring occurs in a given string

Tags: iphone, ios, string, algorithm

I am looking for the quickest and simplest way to determine whether or not a **one word** substring occurs in a given **right-to-left** string.

If it's worth noting, I am going to be implementing the algorithm using **Objective C** and in an **iPhone app**. I have also searched for this algorithm, and found algorithms such as KMP, or BM, which as I figured, were ment to be used for **more-than-one-word** substring. If my assumption is wrong, please let me know!

Thanks ahead,
iLyrical.

Comment: the algorithms are different in different situations.
1, you have one word, and every time you should find whether the word occurs in a coming string.
2, you have a given string, and every time you should find whether the string contains a coming word.

Comment: I think my situation is situation number 2, any ideas?

Comment: 1, split the string into words, and put the words into a **hash_table**. 2, every time you got a coming word, find the word in the hash_table. 3, the time complexity is O(1)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

How about:

```
if([string rangeOfString:@" foo "].location != NSNotFound)
    //I found it, yippee!!
```

*edit* Though I've never tried it on a right to left string....And I realize this will not match the first or last word...so after this you will have to check those too :-S

*another edit*  You could also use regular expressions.  The `NSRegularExpression` class will allow you to do this.  The one you want it `\s*foo\s*`

Comment: I figured out regular expressions are the best solution in my case, thank you for helping me discover them ;) !

Answer (score 1):

A simple and efficient way would be to create a dictionary of all words (a hash table) by splitting the string and then checking if the word exists in the hash table.

Answer (score 1):

```
NSString *string = @"abc def xyz";
if ([string rangeOfString:@"abc"].location == NSNotFound) {
 NSLog(@"string does not contain abc");
} 
else {
 NSLog(@"string contains abc");
 }
```

Hope, this will you...

Answer (score 0):

It worth nothing,if you mean word exactly compare. The simplest way is to compare one by one , and only need to read the parent string once.